# how to select data range with google sheets API when number of columns is unknown?

Tags: python, google-sheets-api

I am converting a script that was originally done in App Script to apply formatting to google sheets.

This script needs to apply to many sheets, and the number of columns is not known in advance.  Before, in the App Scripts, I used basic `getDataRange()` without parameters, and it would select the correct number of columns and rows. How can I do the same via API?  Is there a way to set end column index to end of data range?

For example, I'm using

```
{
      "setBasicFilter": {
        "filter": {
          "range": {
            "sheetId": SHEET_ID,
            "startRowIndex": 0
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

To set top row as a filter.  But it applies filters to all the empty cells as well, that are outside the table with data, while I need them to stop at last column.

[image]

What is the best way to do this via the API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution:

You can call `spreadsheets.values.get` to get the values of a range, then get the length of the first element array. Then plug it in the `setBasicFilter` request.

**Sample Code:**

```
# The ID and range of a sample spreadsheet.
SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID = 'enter spreadsheet ID here'
SAMPLE_RANGE_NAME = 'Sheet1!A1:1'

.
.
.

    # Call the Sheets API
    sheet = service.spreadsheets()
    result = sheet.values().get(spreadsheetId=SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID,
                                range=SAMPLE_RANGE_NAME).execute()
    values = result.get('values', [])
    length = len(values[0])

.
.
.
      # filter parameters
{
      "setBasicFilter": {
        "filter": {
          "range": {
            "sheetId": SHEET_ID,
            "startRowIndex": 0
            "startColumnIndex": 0
            "endColumnIndex" : length
          }
        }
      }
}
```

**References:**

[Python Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python)

[Grid Range](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/other#GridRange)